# add_action not using 'delete_post' action with wp_delete_post

Tags: posts, actions

I am using wp_delete_post function to delete the selected posts shown on the front-end (in my theme page). Posts are being deleted successfully.

```
// delete all selected posts
foreach( $_POST['list_id'] as $listID ) {
   if( wp_delete_post( $listID ) ) {
      echo 'hi';
   }
}
```

In my function.php file i added the following hook for the delete_post.

```
// Delete Post Attachment
function abc_delete_attachment($post_id) {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null,
                    'post_parent' => $post_id ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           if( wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID,true ) ) {
              // Just to check if the hook is called or not i used wp_redirect 
                  wp_redirect(site_url());
           }
        }
    }
}
add_action('delete_post','abc_delete_attachment');
```

But for some reason, this action is not being called. and the attachments are not being deleted permanently rather they are left unattached (the default behavior).

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `before_delete_post` action. As its already very late when `delete_post` action is run. Wordpress un-attach all the attachments before running `delete_post` action. So when you run `get_posts` in your `delete_attachment` function there are no attachments found.

So you need to hook your function to `before_delete_post`.

```
add_action('before_delete_post','abc_delete_attachment');
```

Comment: I was testing before_delete_post hook when you replied. Thanks for confirming the solution :P

Comment: Glad that you were able to figure it out your self. :)

Comment: With `delete_post` action `$attachments` will be just empty array